# Get values for (almost) matching keys in 2 dictionaries and join them

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, dictionary, dictionary-comprehension

So I want to get values for (almost) matching keys in 2 dictionaries and join them. I tried:

```
dict3 = {key:dict1[key].strip() for key in dict2.keys() if key.partition('__')[0] in dict1}
```

...but I dont get any results because it's not finding any matches, my dicts are below, I know i'm close but I'm missing something:

dict1:

```
{
    "h1__display-3": "",
    "h1__display-3_text-white_text-center": "",
    "h1__mt-4": "",
    "h1__mt-5": "",
    "h1__mt-5_kakabum": "",
    "h1__my-4": "",
    "h2__card-title": "",
    "h2__mt-4": "",
    "h2__my-4": ""
}
```

dict2:

```
{
    "h1": "<h1>[]</h1>",
    "h2": "<h2>[]</h2>"
}
```

Desired outcome:

```
{
    "h1": "<h1>[]</h1>",
    "h1__display-3": "<h1>[]</h1>",
    "h1__display-3_text-white_text-center": "<h1>[]</h1>",
    "h1__mt-4": "<h1>[]</h1>",
    "h1__mt-5": "<h1>[]</h1>",
    "h1__mt-5_kakabum": "<h1>[]</h1>",
    "h1__my-4": "<h1>[]</h1>",
    "h2": "<h2>[]</h2>",
    "h2__card-title": "<h2>[]</h2>",
    "h2__mt-4": "<h2>[]</h2>",
    "h2__my-4": "<h2>[]</h2>"
}
```

I was hoping that running the first line of code would work, but I dont think i have the syntax right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Breaking the dict construction out into an ordinary loop mkaes it a little easier to follow.  We want

```
res = {}
for k in dict1:
    key = k.split('__')[0]
    if key in dict2:
        res[k] = dict2[key]
```

which is equivalent to

```
res = {k: dict2[k.split('__')[0]] for k in dict1 if k.split('__')[0] in dict2}
```

This doesn't add `h1` and `h2` as keys, but that's easily accomplished with

```
res.update(dict2)
```